# Table-layout:fixed is not working IE7

Tags: html, css

I am using a table with multiple rows. Only in few rows there are more than one column. I have given the width of the table to be 980px. But the first column takes 980px, and the 2 column goes out of the 980px. I used table-layout:fixed. its not working IE7.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
   table{
        table-layout:fixed;
        *table-layout:fixed;
        width:960px;
        min-width:50px
        }
    td{
        border:1px solid black;
      }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <table>
 <tr>  <td>SomeTextSomeTextSomeTextSomeTextSomeTextSomeTextSomeTextSomeTextSomeTextSomeTextSomeTextSomeTextSomeTextSomeText</td></tr>
 <tr><td> SomeTextSomeTextSomeTextSomeTextSomeText</td>
 <td> SomeTextSomeText</td></tr>
 <tr><td>SomeTextSomeText</td> </tr>
 </table>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I usually use a hack to fix in IE, something like *table-layout:fixed. It works for IE8+, but not for IE7.

Comment: ^^this. Even if someone were using Windows XP, they would likely still be running IE8. You are wasting your time worrying about IE7

Comment: I know, but business is working on IE7.

Comment: Guys is there any solution????? Kindly help me with any ideas

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer:
Colspan or colgroup can be used to alter the width of column as per our preferences.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
 table{
    table-layout:fixed;
    *table-layout:fixed;
    width:960px;
    min-width:50px
    }
td{
    border:1px solid black;
  }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <table>
  <tr>  <td colspan ="2">SomeTextSomeTextSomeTextSomeTextSomeTextSomeTextSomeTextSomeTextSomeTextSomeTextSomeTextSomeTextSomeTextSomeText</td>     </tr>
 <tr><td colspan="1"> SomeTextSomeTextSomeTextSomeTextSomeText</td>
  <td> SomeTextSomeText</td>.    </tr>
  <tr><td>SomeTextSomeText</td>    </tr>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
```